# How to turn local ip address into domain

Tags: web-applications, dns

I've build a webapp with `bottle.py` and `python paste server`. The webapp only works in the local network and this is fine, but I don't want to remember the ip adress of the webserver who is serving all the time.
How can i change the domain i have to type in the browser, for example from
'192.168.0.3' to 'mywebapp'.
The server isn't connected to the internet, all just local.

Comment: Hi. Sounds like [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about) might be a better place for this question. The fact that it's written in Python doesn't seem relevant to the answers that you seek.

Comment: Run a local DNS server. Or if you just have a couple of machines on your network, edit the hosts files by hand.

Comment: I will try the DNS server, because i will have lots of machines accessing to the server. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to run a DNS server. Most OS's support a local hosts file, and making an entry in there that translates to the require IP address should be all you need to do. On Unix [it will be `/etc/hosts`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hosts) and I am happy to say I have forgotten where it lives on Windows.

Comment: So i just have to change the hosts file of the webserver? Will this also work for mobile devices, because this is mainly my goal

Comment: The python paste server documentation talks about using a nameserver... is this a valid approach?

Comment: Sure it's a valid approach if you have a DNS server under your control. I can't speak to mobile devices, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Edist the hosts file on your computer to point to the IP address you want.